# Have different file for Menu in Java

Tags: java, file, inheritance, menu, menubar

I have a program and since the menu is going to be really long I wanted it in a separate file called Menu.java to keep it organized.  But I'm trying to figure out how I can implement that menu in the main class (Called GUI.java which extends JFrame)

In Menu.java there is a method 'public void buildMenu()' that creates the menu, but how can I return that menu to the main program and set it as the menu bar?

Comment: Please include some code for context.

Comment: You can either return a `JMenuBar` instance from the `buildMenu()` method, or you could also extend `JMenuBar` and create an instance of that from `GUI.java`.